# C# object destroying its parent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D game in Unity. I have an object, which destroys everything it touches. When I start the game, the object instantly destroys its parent and itself. I would like it to destroy objects on collision, but not if object is its parent. Is there a way to do it? (isnt there something like isParent?)

Code is here:

```
if (other.CompareTag("Room"))
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            Debug.Log("Room Destroyed");
        }
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (other.CompareTag("Room") && transform.parent != other.gameObject.transform)
{
  Destroy(other.gameObject);
}
```

Though, you might want to check if `other` is anywhere in this object's hierarchy, rather than just checking to see if it's the immediate parent.

Comment: Ï have just tried it and it works! Thank you so much for help.